# How do I know if my WP Theme is using infamous TimThumb?

Tags: hacked

Is there a way to know if my current WordPress theme is using the infamous TimThumb plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to install a security plugin. Most scan for Tim Thumb throughout your whole file structure, including themes (and will also search for many other types of vulnerabilities if you've been hacked, as your "hacked" tag indicates).

You can also search for files named "timthumb" in your theme directory, or search for the phrase "timthumb" in all files on your site. It helps if you have a local copy and a good editor that will search through files.

Comment: We are running Sucuri's plugin and firewall

Comment: Sucuri specifically states they scan for TimThumb, so you'll be notified if it creeps into your site.